# How to add popular items web part for each user for given amount of time

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, kql

I have added most popular items web part in SharePoint online 2016 website i have created.Is it possible change the query of the web part so it only displays users most clicked items for given amount of time like 3 months?

Comment: you can add this `Created > "this month-3"` in addition filters from build query

Comment: @InnovaITveSolutions thanks I think it worked. Is their some documentation online where i can find list of filters that i can used for querys  for web parts in SharePoint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This filter condition here `Created > "this month-3"` is called **Keyword Query Language (KQL)** which is used by Search web part and other web parts in SharePoint to filter the content.

You can find more filter Parameters [here](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/general-development/keyword-query-language-kql-syntax-reference)